# The meaning of 加えてみた in this sentence

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

> 「またぁ。　圭一くんは何にでもケチャップ掛けるね」

> 「せっかく作ったんだから、タルタルをつけてみてよ。　今日はアレンジを加えてみた自信作なんだから」

What exactly is 加えてみた in this sentence? I seems unable to understand it

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you don’t understand about 加えてみた?

Comment: Yes, more detail is needed especially when you didn't seem to have any difficulty understanding つけてみてよ.

Comment: I'm fairly unsure on the meaning of 加えてみた to begin with. To add? アレンジを加えて to try to add an adaption of a recipe?